# How do I avoid html entities in the view in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

So my data is being saved in mysql with actual apostrophes etc. But when CakePHP spits it out in the View like this: `If you&#039;re on this page`

I don't want to have to do `htmlspecialchars_decode()` on every string in my app. Is there a CakePHP solution for this kind of issue?

Here is the echo of the text:

`<?php echo $this->Text->autoLinkUrls(h($item['Item']['post_comment'])); ?>`

Here is the field info for post_comment:
[image: post_comment info]

And here is the form field it's being submitted as:

```
echo $this->Form->textarea('post_comment', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Ask a question or post a link', 'rows' => '3', 'class'=> 'u-full-width'));
```

**EDIT:**
What's even stranger is - that in other parts of the app, apostrophes come out just fine.

Comment: @sgtBOSE thanks - do you think autoLinkUrls is doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autoLinkUrls` takes the options same as `link()`. SO it could help. Try with -

```
<?php echo $this->Text->autoLinkUrls(h($item['Item']['post_comment']), array('escape' => false)); ?>
```

Comment: Wow. What a beautiful solution. Thank you!

Comment: It made me wait before I could. You were too fast. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want to have to do htmlspecialchars_decode() on every string in my app. Is there a CakePHP solution for this kind of issue?

Yes, you need to understand that everything that is passed through the CakePHP core helpers is sanitized internally before rendering by using the `h()` function of CakePHP which is a convenience function for `htmlspecialchars()`. *Be aware that third party helpers might not do that!* So check  them.

I think nearly all helper methods have an option to disable the escaping:

```
$this->Helper->method($foo, ['escape' => false]);
```

Make sure that you don't accidentally allow output of malicius strings when disabling it.